# How to add a line of text to a text file every thursday with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a textfile with a list of the newest minecraft snapshots which then gets displayed on my personel site, the problem is that I have to manually add the snapshot name every thursday and I cant find any way to automate this process.

The text file is laid out like this:

12w26a;

12w25a;

12w24a;

'12' stands for the current year, 'w' just stands for week, '26' indicated what number snapshot it is and 'a' isn't really important but has to be there.

I found some PHP online to automate the process but apparently it no longer works

http://pastebin.com/LP3WKCiZ

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

EDIT:
Here is a live demo of the above code (not sure why its not working since Mojang have gone back to just using jar files again)
http://langkid1.me/pre/

Comment: so you want to run a file every thursday which will have the code to add the snapshot name?

Comment: Did you add a similar - weekly - cron job as mentioned in the comments above the script?

Comment: you said the code no longer works. Can you provide us what error message it generates?

Comment: Here is a live demo of the code I posted http://langkid1.me/pre/

Mojang have gone back to only using jar files again so the code should work but it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Create a php page that reads the text file contents and then checks whether another snapshot exists via the file_exists() function, and if it does it should update the text file that maintains the list.

Now create a script that contains a curl command to the php page.

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://localhost/update.php
```

And finally you just need to set up a cron job to run the script every Thursday.

```
0 0 * * 4 sh /path/script.sh
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you very much I will give this a try. :)

I would upvote you but it says I need 15 reputation points.

Comment: You can also run php scripts from command line. No need to call a url. Just run the script with the cron job.

Comment: Yes ofcourse. For that matter, its even possible to write just a script in bash to check whether file exists and add line to the text file.